# Connected diagrams of several fields

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, path-integral

Consider the following diagram of two *different* scalar fields (say $\psi$ and $\phi$)
[image]

This diagram is the trivial zero order term in perturbation (in real space) for the correlator $\langle\phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)\psi(x_3)\psi(x_4)\rangle $. **Is this diagram considered connected or not?** Most books consider same fields when explaining about connected graphs, so the generalization is ambiguous. Can you provide a definition (and a reference) to "connected graphs" for several (not necessary scalar) fields?

Comment: The diagram is not connected.  I believe the definition of connected means that you can't factorize the function $\langle\phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)\psi(x_3)\psi(x_4)\rangle = \langle\phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)\rangle\langle\psi(x_3)\psi(x_4)\rangle $.